# find the rate of change of a function at a point in the direction perpendicular to the a plane and moving away from the origin.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am stumped on how to solve this type of problem. If anyone could give me a hand it would be appreciated.

Let f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2. At the point (1, 2, 1), find the rate of change of f in the direction perpendicular to the plane x+2y+3z=8 and moving away from the origin.

Thanks.

Comment: Try translating your plane equation into point-normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Hint the Unit Vector along the direction of the plane (1,2,3)/|(1,2,3)|

Duf(x,y,z)=(2x,2y,2z) = (2,4,2)

Then rate of change of f(x,y,z) perpendicular to the plane  = (2,4,2).[(1,2,3)/|(1,2,3)|]